# Getting Fatal Error Uncaught exception 'Balanced\Errors\Declined'

Tags: balanced-payments

When am trying to debit a card

VISA    4444444444444448    123 Processor Failure

which gives a fatal error Uncaught exception 'Balanced\Errors\Declined'.

so am not able to catch the error or response from balanced.

Is there a way to capture this kind of errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrap that code in a try/catch and catch that exception. You'll then be able to get more information out of it.